# Wordpress CSS not applied

Tags: css, wordpress, web

I am building a site with wordpress. I have built some pages but now I noticed that when I go from one page to the other CSS is loaded but not applied. To be applied I have either to refresh the page or change the screen size, and it is applied automatically.

That's very confusing. I tried deleting the cache and follow the same steps from incognito mode but still the same problem appears.

Why is that happening and how I can solve it.

Thank you all!

Comment: How are you adding your css? I guess the theme's CSS loads after your custom CSS & it's overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too this and I've had a similar issue but I'm not sure if it's gonna work for you

When I used a template theme from Wordpress, the CSS wouldnt be applied at all(Or apply but not update). but creating a blank theme from scratch it solved the issue. So if you're running one of the templates, try to change too one you created on your own if you havent already!

Comment: I dont use blank templates and I cant right now change the template that I use :(